# How to get Elasticsearch actual result size

Tags: elasticsearch

I am not asking the count for the search response. what I am asking is, size of the result(_source) that took Elasticsearch's hard-disk memory. is it possible to find such?. Why I am asking is, I need to find which type of source takes maximum size for an index. thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean the total documents that matched your query?

Comment: yes. the total documents that matches my query. @LMK

Comment: im not asking total-count. what im asking is the disk-space of the search

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the _size field in your mapping. So this is data is created at index time.

```
{
    "tweet" : {
        "_size" : {"enabled" : true, "store" : true }
    }
}
```

Check out the [size field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-size-field.html) documentation.

Then you can return this field by adding it to the fields list in the query.
See [the Fields documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-fields.html) for how to do that.